# Are JSF Views shared between users?

Tags: jsf, memory, view, sharing

I've defined the # of logical views and views in session attributes in web.xml to 1, so that there is only a maximum of 1 view. Given that, I've a couple of questions:

- Is this # specific to a given user? Meaning, does this limit the # of views to 1 per user?
  ** If yes, could there be multiple view representations of the same JSP across multiple users?
- Is there a way to share the JSF view across users (given that the view is rather generic and does not contain any user specific data)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your generic definition of "an user" *actually*  equals to "a HTTP session", then yes, you're right. Views are basically stored in the HTTP session and referenced by a hidden HTML input field with the name `javax.faces.ViewState`. Different HTTP sessions will not share their views with each other, that would otherwise obviously have been a huge bug and security hole.

With setting the number of (logical) views in session to `1`, you're however removing the possibility that the user can use multiple views containing POST forms in different windows/tabs in the same session. Everytime the enduser opens a new window/tab, the enduser will receive a `ViewExpiredException` whenever the enduser fires a POST request in a previous window/tab, because you've configured it to keep only **one** view in the session, which is the last opened one.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. Hmm.. :-( What's the best way to deal with rather static (aka, read-only) views in JSF, in that case? Assume that most of a page is generic to the user base barring some exceptions, so I wan't to reuse the existing views as much as possible across sessions (in the interest of reducing the overall memory footprint). Is this not possible in a JSF (within a portlet) world? Hope not.

Comment: I don't want the additional overhead of a request scoped bean (as it is going to increase the # of initializations). I am more leaning towards an application scoped bean given the nature of the data and it being generic to the user population. You mentioned "view scope" but I am not using a view scope. What I am still not clear about is this - every JSP is going to result in a unique view (for a given session). While I can play with the scoping of the referenced beans, I want to be able to share the same view (given its generic nature) across the sessions thereby, cutting the total # of views.

Comment: A view is only created and stored in session whenever it contains a POST form as in `<h:form>`. If you don't have any of them (also not for plain page-to-page navigation!), then you also don't need to worry about this. By the way, with JSF 2.x the average view size is really greatly reduced as opposed to JSF 1.x thanks to the new partial state saving mechanism. The state contains then just the necessary form components instead of the entire markup.

Comment: Please disregard my 1st comment which you apparently saw before I deleted it. I mixed your question with another question. I already deleted it.

Comment: Given that the 1st step in a JSF Lifecycle is "Restore View", wouldn't a view either be created or restored (one of the two) regardless of whether the JSP has <h:form> tags or otherwise? All of the JSF code is within a <f:view> element, of course.

Comment: Perhaps you had JSF 1.0/1.1 in mind. Since JSF 1.2, a view is only saved when it has a `<h:form>`. The same view is only restored on a POST request (since there's none available in the session on a GET request). Since JSF 2.0, only the portion containing `UIForm`, `UIInput`, `UICommand` components and so on is been saved instead of the whole view.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. Appreciate all the leads!

Comment: Okay, I did a lot of heap analysis and have a reasonably better handle of the JSF object distribution. Yet, I don't see a way to keep the JSF memory footprint from growing (RichFaces AJAXStateHolder, to be specific) as the # of users increases EVEN THOUGH my pages are quite generic to the user population and have little, if anything, to do with a specific user.